# Saving the int value of a char into an int variable

Tags: c

There are hundreds of questions on the net about this topic but are not what I'm looking for. I am looking for a way to convert a character to its ascii value.

I don't mean display the ascii value. I mean an actual value in a variable that I can use. Just changing the place holder is not going to work for this. That only **displays** the value.  I need the actual working value. To be more specific I want to type in a character and have its ascii value saved into an int variable.

Ex.. enter 'A' and then the variable `someVariable` is initialized with the value 65. Then I want to add a constant value of 20 to the value 65 (or whatever the case would be for that character), to get 85, and then use that resulting number for the reference index of an array.

So you see I need to actually convert the value to an int not a char displayed as an int.

Comment: You can use chars in the way you describe. What is the issue? This is more or less a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719187/using-char-as-array-index-in-c

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help regarding appropriate questions and how to ask them.

Comment: `int`, `char`, `short`, `long`... They are all integral types, with the only difference being their sizes. It just so happens that you can use `printf` with `"%c"` and display what you refer to as a character. But at the end of the day, a `char` variable stores a whole number, just as an `int` variable does (more precisely, they store a bit sequence which is eventually treated by the underlying HW architecture as an integer.

Comment: And BTW, `short` and `long` are just abbreviations for `short int` and `long int`. Not sure why they didn't do the same with `char` (somebody at the IEEE committee should have suggested something like `very short int` IMO).

Comment: @barakmanos they probably should have used fixed width types from the get-go ... `long long` means `int64_t` for almost all intents and purposes

Comment: @M.M: They eventually did (`int16_t`, `int32_t`, etc), didn't they? But the problem remaining is that those types do not necessarily correlate the same primitive types (`short`, `int`, etc) on every platform.

Comment: Your execution character set probably isn't ASCII. It can be critically important to know what it is so it's best not to call it ASCII unless that's exactly what it is. It is possibly ISO 8859-1, Windows-1252 or similar. So, if someone types '~' and you add 20, you'll know what you're getting. Is it '’'? (Me, I can't figure the meaning of 'A' + 20. Maybe you're dealing with the alphabet of some language's writing system and it happens to be in a recognized order for the character set encoding you are using.)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make a character an ascii value and assign it to an int like the example below. You can also add to the value and convert it to a different ascii character.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                             
int main(void)                                                                 
{                                                                              
    char c ='A';                                                               
    int ascii = (int)c;//Convert to ascii value                                                        
    printf("%d\n",ascii);                                                      

    ascii += 20; //value is now 85                                             

    printf("%d\n",ascii);                                                      

    char d = ascii - '0'; //convert back to new character.                     

    printf("%c\n",d);                                                          
}       

output:
65
85
%
```

Comment: Casting to an int does not "convert to ascii value".